# In regular expression what is the difference between 1- > (0+1)* ¦¦ 2-> (0*+1*)*

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

Okay i understand that (1) means any combination of 0 and 1 of any length  but doesn't (2) mean the same??
Like any combination of any combination of 0 or 1?

Comment: Please read documanation Of Regular Exp.. Then Ask Question Here

Comment: Yep sorry my mistake, its in the closure law

Answer (score 0):

Given the Regular Expressions

(i)(0+1)*
(ii)(0*+1*)*

According to the identies of the Regular Expressions,(i)=(ii)

Clarification with image

[image: 1]